# Convert CamelCase to under_score_case in php __autoload()

Tags: php, autoload, camelcasing

PHP manual [suggests](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to autoload classes like

```
function __autoload($class_name){
 require_once("some_dir/".$class_name.".php");
}
```

and this approach works fine to load class `FooClass` saved in the file `my_dir/FooClass.php` like

```
class FooClass{
  //some implementation
}
```

**Question**

How can I make it possible to use `_autoload()` function and access `FooClass` saved in the file `my_dir/foo_class.php`?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You could convert the class name like this...

```
function __autoload($class_name){
    $name = strtolower(preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1_$2', $class_name));
    require_once("some_dir/".$name.".php");
}
```

Comment: Would this not have issues with a class name like *myClassName*?

Comment: Thanks for the answer rikh, your magic works! @cballou, the code works in your case too. I tested it on the following class names FooClass, fooClass, myFooClass and MyFooClass.

Comment: @cballou, nope, every time there is a lower case letter followed by an upper case letter, an underscore is inserted between them. Finally, a call to strtolower is made to ensure the final name is all lower case.

Comment: Note: This will transform MyCClassName to my_cclass_name and not my_c_class_name.

Comment: Per comment from @DanielG if you want every uppercase letter except the first to result in an underscore: `strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<!^)([A-Z])/', '_$1', $class_name))`. The only difference between this and answer provided by @rik-heywood is that MyCClassName becomes my_c_class_name instead of my_cclass_name.

Comment: To handle more complicated (asinine) names, like `FooBARBazAndTHeLike => foo_bar_baz_and_t_he_like`, you can use (but shouldn't!) `strtolower(preg_replace('/((?<=[a-z])[A-Z])|((?<=[A-Z])[A-Z](?=[a-z]))/', _$1$2, $class_name))`.  http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/dqi

Answer (score 2):

This is untested but I have used something similar before to convert the class name.  I might add that my function also runs in O(n) and doesn't rely on slow backreferencing.

```
// lowercase first letter
$class_name[0] = strtolower($class_name[0]);

$len = strlen($class_name);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
    // see if we have an uppercase character and replace
    if (ord($class_name[$i]) > 64 && ord($class_name[$i]) < 91) {
        $class_name[$i] = '_' . strtolower($class_name[$i]);
        // increase length of class and position
        ++$len;
        ++$i;
    }
}

return $class_name;
```

Comment: It'd be cleaner if you got rid of the magic numbers and used something closer to: if(ord($class_name[$i]) >= ord('A') && ord($class_name[$i]) <= ord('Z')) {

Comment: This is true, however I was going for optimization as two more calls to **ord()** within a loop would be slightly excessive IMO.

Comment: $class_name[$i] = '_' . strtolower($class_name[$i]); // WHAT ?