# preg_replace() versus ord()

Tags: php, function, comparison, performance

What is quicker, for camelCase to underscores, `preg_replace()` or `ord()`?

My guess is that using `ord()` will be quicker, since `preg_replace()` can do much more than needed.

```php
function __autoload($class_name) {
  $name = strtolower(preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1_$2', $class_name));
  require_once "some_dir/" . $name . ".php";
}
```

```php
function __autoload($class_name) {
  $class_name[0] = strtolower($class_name[0]);
    
  $len = strlen($class_name);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
    if (ord($class_name[$i]) > ord('A') && ord($class_name[$i]) < ord('Z')) {
      $class_name[$i] = '_' . strtolower($class_name[$i]);
      ++$len;
      ++$i;
    }
  }
    
  return $class_name;
}
```

#### Disclaimer

Code examples are taken from [Convert CamelCase to under_score_case in php __autoload()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589468/convert-camelcase-to-under-score-case-in-php-autoload).

#### Edit

After [jensgram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52162/jensgram)'s array-suggestion and finding [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php), I have come up with the following.

```php
function __autoload ($string) {
  $string = str_split($string);
  $pos = count($string);

  while (--$pos > 0) {
    $lower = strtolower($string[$pos]);

    if ($string[$pos] === $lower) {
      continue;
    }
    
    unset($string[$pos]);
    array_splice($string, $pos, 0, array('_', $lower));
  }

  $string  =  implode('', $string);
  return $string;
}
```

When I will test these methods, I will add this one, but feel free to tell me your results anytime.

Comment: The best way to tell what is quicker is to try it. Have you?

Comment: Grab your favorite profiler and benchmark

Comment: maybe interesting for the people reading the following: http://www.paulferrett.com/2009/php-camel-case-functions/ http://www.webdevblog.info/php/convert-strings-between-camelcasepascalcase-and-underscored-notation/

Comment: bwah, i'll put that on my todo list, this is just a question that could be answered by someone who has already done this and/or is good in the know of profiling/benchmarking.

Comment: For clarity's sake, there is: `camelCase`, `PascalCase`, `snake_case`, `kebab-case`, and `sanitized-slug-formatting-with-whitelisted-characters`.  When considering conversion techniques, be sure to test fringe cases with numbers, symbols, consecutive uppercase, multibyte characters and whatever else you might encounter. Additional resources: [How to convert PascalCase to snake_case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1993721/2943403) and [Convert string with dashes to camelCase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2791998/2943403)

Comment: and [Using preg_replace() to convert alphanumeric strings from camelCase to snake_case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40514051/2943403) and [Replace snake_case to CamelCase in part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38726530/2943403) and [Change all php variable from snake_case/underscore_case to camelCase using regex and vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74846493/2943403) and [Recursively convert all keys in a multi-dimensional array to snake_case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1444484/2943403)

Comment: [Convert snake_case to camelCase in PHPStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53024625/2943403) and [All text from camelCase to SNAKE_CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43768435/2943403) and [Laravel Eloquent camel case in API, snake case in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76571835/2943403) and [camelCase to dash - two capitals next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10507789/2943403) and [Convert array keys from underscore_case to camelCase recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31274782/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think (and i'm pretty much sure) that the preg_replace method will be faster - but if you want to know, why dont you do a little benchmark calling both functions 100000 times and measure the time?

Answer (score 0):

*(Not an answer but too long to be a comment - will CW)*

*If* you're going to compare, you should at least optimize a little on the `ord()` version.

```
$len = strlen($class_name);
$ordCurr = null;
$ordA = ord('A');
$ordZ = ord('Z');
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
    $ordCurr = ord($class_name[$i]);
    // see if we have an uppercase character and replace
    if ($ordCurr >= $ordA && $ordCurr <= $ordZ) {
        $class_name[$i] = '_' . strtolower($class_name[$i]);
        // increase length of class and position
        ++$len;
        ++$i;
    }
}
```

Also, pushing the name onto a stack (an array) and joining at the end might prove more efficient than string concatenation.

**BUT** Is this worth the optimization / profiling in the first place?

Comment: more useful as well, `$class_name[$i] = '_' . strtolower($class_name[$i]);` does not work as expected...

Comment: @immeëmosol No, at least you should maintain a new string for the result. I didn't really dig into the code - just wanted to illustrate some simple techniques :)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is convert camel case to underscores, you can probably write a more efficient function to do so than either ord or preg_replace in less time than it takes to profile them.

Answer (score 0):

My usecase was slightly different than the OP's, but I think it's still illustrative of the difference between preg_replace and manual string manipulation.

```
$a = "16 East, 95 Street";

echo "preg: ".test_preg_replace($a)."\n";
echo "ord:  ".test_ord($a)."\n";

$t = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i &lt 100000; $i++) test_preg_replace($a);
echo (microtime(true) - $t)."\n";
$t = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i &lt 100000; $i++) test_ord($a);
echo (microtime(true) - $t)."\n";

function test_preg_replace($s) {
    return preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_-]/', '-', strtolower($s));
}
function test_ord($s) {
    $a = ord('a');
    $z = ord('z');
    $aa = ord('A');
    $zz = ord('Z');
    $zero = ord('0');
    $nine = ord('9');
    $us = ord('_');
    $ds = ord('-');
    $toret = ''; 
    for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($s); $i < $len; $i++) {
        $c = ord($s[$i]);
        if (($c >= $a && $c &lt;= $z) 
            || ($c >= $zero && $c &lt;= $nine)
            || $c == $us 
            || $c == $ds)
        {   
            $toret .= $s[$i];
        }   
        elseif ($c >= $aa && $c &lt;= $zz)
        {   
            $toret .= chr($c + $a - $aa); // strtolower
        }   
        else
        {   
            $toret .= '-';
        }   
    }   
    return $toret;
}
```

The results are

```
0.42064881324768
2.4904868602753
```

so the preg_replace method is vastly superior. Also, string concatenation is slightly faster than inserting into an array and imploding it.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a benchmark using the following four functions and I figured out that the one implemented in Magento is the fastest one (it's Test4):

Test1:

```
/**
 * @see: http://www.paulferrett.com/2009/php-camel-case-functions/
 */
function fromCamelCase_1($str)
{
    $str[0] = strtolower($str[0]);
    return preg_replace('/([A-Z])/e', "'_' . strtolower('\\1')", $str);
}
```

Test2:

```
/**
 * @see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995338/phps-preg-replace-versusvs-ord#answer-3995435
 */
function fromCamelCase_2($str)
{
    // lowercase first letter
    $str[0] = strtolower($str[0]);

    $newFieldName = '';
    $len = strlen($str);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
        $ord = ord($str[$i]);
        // see if we have an uppercase character and replace
        if ($ord > 64 && $ord < 91) {
            $newFieldName .= '_';
        }
        $newFieldName .= strtolower($str[$i]);
    }
    return $newFieldName;
}
```

Test3:

```
/**
 * @see: http://www.paulferrett.com/2009/php-camel-case-functions/#div-comment-133
 */
function fromCamelCase_3($str) {
    $str[0] = strtolower($str[0]);
    $func = create_function('$c', 'return "_" . strtolower($c[1]);');
    return preg_replace_callback('/([A-Z])/', $func, $str);
}
```

Test4:

```
/**
 * @see: http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6-trunk/lib/Varien/Object.php :: function _underscore($name)
 */
function fromCamelCase_4($name) {
    return strtolower(preg_replace('/(.)([A-Z])/', "$1_$2", $name));
}
```

Result using the string "getExternalPrefix" 1000 times:

```
fromCamelCase_1: 0.48158717155457
fromCamelCase_2: 2.3211658000946
fromCamelCase_3: 0.63665509223938
fromCamelCase_4: 0.18188905715942
```

Result using random strings like "WAytGLPqZltMfHBQXClrjpTYWaEEkyyu" 1000 times:

```
fromCamelCase_1: 2.3300149440765
fromCamelCase_2: 4.0111720561981
fromCamelCase_3: 2.2800230979919
fromCamelCase_4: 0.18472790718079
```

Using the test-strings I got a different output - but this should not appear in your system:

```
original:
MmrcgUmNfCCTOMwwgaPuGegEGHPzvUim

last test:
mmrcg_um_nf_cc_to_mwwga_pu_geg_eg_hpzv_uim

other tests:
mmrcg_um_nf_c_c_t_o_mwwga_pu_geg_e_g_h_pzv_uim
```

As you can see at the timestamps - the last test has the same time in both tests :)