# Replace snake_case to CamelCase in part of a string

Tags: php

I have a uri that looks like:

```
/Albums/album_id/Photos/photo_id/tags
```

I want to replace `album_id` and `photo_id` with `AlbumId` and `PhotoId`. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, that does not work, most probably because of the `/` in the word. Just copy paste the string I provided. The changes to `/Albums/albumId/Photos/photoId/tags` (the `album` and `photo` are still lowercase)

Comment: Consider exploding on `/`, loop through it, replace `_` with space, put it through `ucwords` and then implode on `/`.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/YcDkK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could also try this:

```
$str = "/Albums/album_id/Photos/photo_id/tags";
$str = str_replace("_", "", ucwords($str, " /_"));
```

Reference to [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) (It does allow a second parameter despite some of these php online testers stating otherwise...)

Comment: I think, output isn't as desired according to instructions. It gives output `/Albums/AlbumId/Photos/PhotoId/Tags`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another one-liner:

```
echo implode('', array_map('ucfirst', explode('_', $string)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following:

```
str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', str_replace('/', '/ ', $uri))));
```

**Explanation**

The prefix `/` does not allow `foo_bar` to become `FooBar` when using `ucwords(str_replace('_', '', $uri))`.

So instead, first replace `/` with `/` (i.e. add a space after the slash), and at the end remove all spaces.

Comment: I was going to suggest a slightly shorter version: str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace(['_', '/'], [' ', '/ '], $uri))

Comment: That will give you /Albums/AlbumId/Photos/PhotoId/Tags, that changes more than just '_' it makes the other words upper too. Was the expected behavior?

Comment: I think, output isn't as desired according to instructions. It gives output `/Albums/AlbumId/Photos/PhotoId/Tags` as Franklin above me mentioned.

Comment: this will give you what you want, tested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38727024/5931957

Answer (score 0):

**2 steps:**

1. Every letter after a _ should be capitalized.
2. _ should be removed

**Implementation:**

Let's make the string a char array:

```
$a = "/Albums/album_id/Photos/photo_id/tags"
$b = str_split($a)
```

Now, every char that follows a `_` should be capitalized:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($b); $i++) {
    if ($b[i - 1] == '_') {
        $b[i] = strtoupper($b[i]);
    }
}
```

Now, making it a string again:

```
$c = implode("", $b);
```

And removing the `_`s

```
e = str_replace("_", "", $c);
```

and a full version:

```
function doThat($t) {
  $b = str_split($t)
  for ($i = 1; $i < count($b); $i++) {
    if ($b[i - 1] == '_') {
      $b[i] = strtoupper($b[i]);
    }
  }
  return str_replace("_", "", implode("", $b));
}
```

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Think it's fixed. Tell me if something's wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect this code:

```
$str = "/Albums/album_id/Photos/photo_id/tags";

$split_str = split("_", $str);

$new_str = $split_str[0];

for ($i = 1; $i < count($split_str); $i++)
{
    $new_str .= ucfirst($split_str[$i]);
}

echo $new_str;
```

[Here you can test it.](http://rextester.com/QUY71028)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is of help:

```
<?php
function convert($string){
  $sections = explode('/',$string);
  $url = '';
  foreach ($sections as $section){
  $words = explode('_',$section);
    if(count($words) > 1){
      foreach ($words as $word){
        $word = ucfirst($word);
        $url .= $word;
      }
    } else {
      $url .= $words[0];
    }
  $url .= '/';
  }
  return $url;
}
$url = convert("/Albums/album_id/Photos/photo_id/tags");
echo $url;
?>
```

This leaves the single lowercase words untouched and only capitalizes and remove dashes for section like ab_cd. There is a slash at the end now which you can ofcourse simple get rid of if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with one call to [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function:

```
$string = '/Albums/album_id/Photos/photo_id/tags';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/_(.)/',
    function($match) {
        return strtoupper($match[1]);
    },
    $string);
```

The weird `/_(.)/` smiley face is actually regex, which matches any character after `_`. The `(.)` is `any character` separated into own group, so that we can use it in matched array in the callback function.

On first regex match, `$match` becomes an array, which holds `0 => _i, 1 => i`, so you can safely use `$match[1]` in the callback function.

The callback function itself only returns the string transformed to upper case.

The output of the above example is `/Albums/albumId/Photos/photoId/tags`

Answer (score 0):

I tested this one and it does the trick for that and other similar strings:
it will convert  **/Albums/album_id/Photos/photo_id/tags** into **/Albums/AlbumId/Photos/PhotoId/tags**

$str = "/Albums/album_id/Photos/photo_id/tags";

```
    $split_str = explode("/", $str);

    $result = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($split_str); $i++)
    {
        $sub_result = $split_str[$i];
        if(strpos($split_str[$i], "_") !== false) {

            $segments = explode("_", $split_str[$i]);
            $sub_result = '';
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($segments); $j++) {
                $sub_result .= ucfirst($segments[$j]);
            }
        }
        if(strlen($sub_result)) { // This will remove the empty string generated by the first part of the url
            $result .= "/" . $sub_result;
        }
    }

    echo $result;
```