# All text from camelCase to SNAKE_CASE

Tags: regex, notepad++, camelcasing, snakecasing

I am trying to do some text manipulations using Notepad++ macros. My last step is converting camelCase strings to SNAKE_CASE. So far no luck. I'm not very familiar with regex so can't write my own solution.

Example text file input:

```
firstLine(874),
secondLine(15),
thirdLineOfText87(0x0001);
```

Desired output:

```
FIRST_LINE(874),
SECOND_LINE(15),
THIRD_LINE_OF_TEXT_87(0x0001);
```

Regex or any plugin is an acceptable answer.

Comment: FYI, according to [a post at the Notepad++ forum](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/130/convert-case-to/4), there are conventions about the case types and its names. So, the correct names for the cases asked are *lowerCamelCase* and *SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE*.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I suggest the following regex approach:

*Find What*:      `(\b[a-z]+|\G(?!^))((?:[A-Z]|\d+)[a-z]*)`
*Replace With*: `\U\1_\2`
*Match Case*: **ON**.

This will turn `camelCase87LikeThis` words to `CAMEL_CASE_87_LIKE_THIS`. If you need to add support for those camel words that start with an uppercase letter, use the following regex modification:

```
(\G(?!^)|\b[a-zA-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*|\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uj9mGm/1) (also tested in Notepad++). Note the placement of the `\G` inside the regex and added `A-Z`.

**Details**:

- `(\b[a-z]+|\G(?!^))` - Group 1 capturing either of the two alternatives:

  - `\b[a-z]+` - start of a word (`\b` is the initial word boundary here) followed with 1+ lowercase ASCII letters
  - `|`- or
  - `\G(?!^)` - the end position of the previous successful match
- `((?:[A-Z]|\d+)[a-z]*)` - Group 2 capturing:

  - `(?:[A-Z]|\d+)` - either an uppercase ASCII letter (`[A-Z]`) or (`|`) 1+ digits (`\d+`)
  - `[a-z]*` - 0+ lowercase ASCII letters.

The `\U\1_\2` replacement pattern turns all the chars to uppercase with `\U` and inserts a `_` between the two groups (inserted with `\1` and `\2` backreferences).

[image]

Comment: How should `find what` look like if camelCases started with upper letter, example: FirstLine(874)?

Comment: First approach misses all `_` except last one, and second approach generates from `ThirdLineOfText87(0x0001);` -> `THIRD_LINEOF_TEXT_87(0x0001);` missed second _

Comment: You may use [`(\G(?!^)|\b[a-zA-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*|\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/uj9mGm/1), the trick was to put `\G` branch as the first alternative in the alternation group and adding support for the uppercase letter at the beginning of the word.

Comment: This replaces `FfdffDF` with `FFDFF_D_F` which, I believe, isn't the desired behavior. Here's a tweaked version that takes into account cases like `SomethingIO` and `IOSomething`: [`(\G(?!^)|\b(?:[A-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z][a-z]*))(?=[a-zA-Z]{2,}|\d)([A-Z](?:[A-Z]|[a-z]*)|\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/Pyz2TK/1).

Comment: hmm.. `MySuperCoolTest.js` becomes `MY_SUPERCoolTest.js` -- i can't get the regex to affect the entire string?

Comment: @ChaseMoskal The regex in the answer is for strings like `caMelCase`, not `CaMelCase`. If you use the regex from [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768435/all-text-from-camelcase-to-snake-case/43768828?noredirect=1#comment74598436_43768828) you will get `MY_SUPER_COOL_TEST.js` (just make sure *Match case* is on)

Comment: @MoacirSchmidt Then you probably want `(\G(?!^)|\b[[:alpha:]][[:lower:]]*)([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*|\d+)|\b([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*)\b` and replace with `\U(?{3}$3:$1_$2)`

Comment: @MoacirSchmidt Not [the one](https://regex101.com/r/uj9mGm/28) in the previous comment.

Comment: On the link you referenced **Pascal** is replaced by a single *_* (underscore)

Comment: @MoacirSchmidt **Because regex101.com is not Notepad++. `\U(?{3}$3:$1_$2)` replacement will work in Notepad++.**

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternate solution. I mean, it saves not only digits together, and abbreviations too (in PHP):

```php
preg_replace(
  '/(?<!^)([A-Z][a-z]|(?<=[a-z])[^a-z]|(?<=[A-Z])[0-9_])/',
  '_$1',
  $str
)
```

This regex will work for these cases:

```
'fat' ---> 'fat'
'fatBat' ---> 'fat_bat'
'FatBat' ---> 'fat_bat'
'camera360' ---> 'camera_360'
'camera360all' ---> 'camera_360all'
'camera360All' ---> 'camera_360_all'
'cameraABC' ---> 'camera_abc'
'cameraABCAll' ---> 'camera_abc_all'
'thirdLineOfText87' ---> 'third_line_of_text_87'
```

This solution to lower case. But if we want upper case, we may use `\U`-modifier as in above solution in notepad++:

- *Find What:* `/(?<!^)([A-Z][a-z]|(?<=[a-z])[^a-z]|(?<=[A-Z])[0-9_])/`
- *Replace With:* `_\1`
- *Match Case:* **ON**.

*I found this solution on doc page of php function preg_replace: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#111695 .*