# Convert snake_case to camelCase in PHPStorm

Tags: formatting, ide, phpstorm, camelcasing, snakecasing

I want to convert all function name from `my_function()` to `myFunction()` and all variables from `my_variable` to `myVariable`. I want a camelCase.

I have used many plugins case converter in PhpStorm, Sublime Text etc. But what they do is, they also change database queries inside commas.

Comment: *"But what they do is, they also change database queries inside commas."* Heh? CamelCase plugin works in PhpStorm. Yes, you need to **use it manually for each occurrence**. If you want to replace ALL occurrences of `my_function()` to `myFunction()` .. try executing `Refactor | Rename` on it.

Answer (score 3):

There are several plugins you can try - [CamelCase](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7160-camelcase) , [String Manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation).
Or, you can just use Find/Replace with regexp

Comment: How would one regexp look like then? I tried but can find a solid dynamic solution. Best I came up with was `(\w+)_(\w+)` and replace with `$1\u$2`

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to find and replace regex to rename methods

- find any method: `(function [a-z]+)_([a-z])`
- replace with: `$1\U$2`
- you might need to run it multiple times

Or

- find any string: `_([a-z])`
- replace with: `\U$1`