# Change all php variable from snake_case/underscore_case to camelCase using regex and vscode

Tags: regex

I found a neat vscode way to convert snake_case to camelCase but it will affect **all** words. I want to limit the search to words with `$` at the beginnig. With what I searched, I need to add `^$` before the string I want to match but unable to properly work it. Below is the way I found in [this github link](https://gist.github.com/Ugotsta/2a271f6440f1ac7e028df55e94035e40)

```
1. Press CTRL-H ( ⌥⌘F on Mac ).
2. Press ALT-R ( ⌥⌘R on Mac ).
3. Type _([a-zA-Z]).
4. Press TAB and type $1.
5. Press ALT-ENTER ( ⌥ENTER on Mac ).
6. Press F1 and type upper, then press ENTER.
7. Press CTRL-ALT-ENTER ( ⌥ENTER on Mac ).
```

meaning change all `$is_data` to `$isData` while words like `_construct` are unchanged.

**EDIT**
To someone that closed my question because he said this is not a question. How to make all PHP variable `$snake_case`/`$underscore_case` to `$camelCase` in VSCODE with REGEX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
(?<=\$\w*)_([a-zA-Z])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AkLMt9/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=\$\w*)`: Lookbehind to assert that there is a `$` followed by 0 or more word characters behind current position
- `_`: Match an underscore
- `([a-zA-Z])`: Match a letter and capture in group #1

Comment: Thank you for answering, however it does not work though. see https://regex101.com/r/TBWDXK/1

Comment: only words that start with $. though it did skip _construct

Comment: the same https://regex101.com/r/nPa8Es/1

Comment: I am asking if `case '$test_construct'` should be left as is or should be replaced with `case '$testConstruct'` ?

Comment: regarding your question case '$test_construct', it should be '$testConstruct. Anything that has a $ sign and in underscore/snake_case, change it to camelCase.

Comment: Tried and and this is great. Hope I can still upvote even if someone closed my question

Answer (score 1):

You can find all words starting with starting `$` and min one underscore using this `\$\w*_\w*` and replace with `$1${2:lower}`.

Comment: This does highlight the strings with `$` at the start and contains underscore. However, continuing with step 4, change `$1` to `$1${2:lower}`, it will change all string to UPPER CASE, (since it highlight everything). If we could limit the highlight to the underscore only, that would be great.